# Fixed aside section that is aware of navigation bar in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you don't know what the title is about take a look at this gif (I couldn't get it to work on jsfiddle)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM6Fa.jpg

The green div would be fixed aside section and the blue div a navigation bar. I created that using jQuery and a plug-in that allows to check if element is on screen.

The problem is it's pretty slow and buggy sometimes. Is there any CSS trick that would give the same effect? Or anything else that doesn't use .Appear() plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, just found better and JS only solution

```
window.onscroll = changePosition;

function changePosition() {
    var aside = document.getElementById("someElement");
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {        //100 is nav bar height
      aside.style.position = "fixed";
      aside.style.top = "20px";  //space between top of the screen and aside
    } else {
        aside.style.position = "absolute";
        aside.style.top = "120px";     //nav bar height + space between them
    }
}
```

Works waaaay better than the one I did with jQuery